# DRF "Unauthorized: <route>" when Authorization header is present from React FE

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, access-token

I'm working on integration with Azure AD. I have my ReactJS FE getting the `accessToken` and now I need to send it to the Django/DRF BE to authenticate it there as well.

At any rate, I'm sending the token as a `Authorization: "Bearer <token>"` and I'm getting a `Unauthorized: <route>` response. If I comment it out, the request goes through.

I'm just trying to understand a couple things:

1. The presence of the `Authorization` header is obviously telling DRF it needs to do something with it. Does something need to be enabled in DRF settings to handle it?
2. Should I be sending this `accessToken` to my API in the headers, or the body, of the `POST` request?

```
// Authentication.js
...
  const testApiAuthentication = async () => {
    let accessToken = await authProvider.getAccessToken();
    setAccessToken(accessToken.accessToken);
    if (accessToken) {
      setAuthenticatingToken(true);
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/api/users/',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  };
...
```

```
# views.py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

# Create your views here.
class TestView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request)
        return Response('Hello World')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my `TestView` to the following and now I get a successful response from the API:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

# Create your views here.
class TestView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request)
        return Response('Hello World')
```

Comment: Is this approach working?

Comment: Here we are not even validating the token with the request